# how do i write a space after a string in a php page redirected from a html page?

Tags: php, string, variables

```
$data .=$_POST["name"];
$data .=$_POST["email"];
```

I want to add a single space after this piece of data so in my php page each string of user's input is separated from each other. I know that i don't ask a difficult question but i always make wel the difficult and fail in easy and foolish things :D I have made a blog about classical greek, added a test with radio buttons, and a php file which manages the input and output of the form. I have succesfully got input from users (really myself), but i wanted that my page with input from users were easy to read so i ought to add spaces between the name, email, and comment of the user beside the result of the test.
Besides, i don't know how to conditionally greet the user according to the number of correct answers...
     
         function show_alert(answers) {
         var red = answers;
         if (red >= 0 && red <= 10){
             var msg = "Bad! You had: " + red + " correct answers!";
         } elseif (red> 10 && red <= 20){
             var msg = "Well! You had " + red + " correct answers!";
         } elseif (red> 20 && red <= 30){
             var msg = "Great! You had " + red + " correct answers!";
         } else {var msg = "Something went wrong! Sorry, try again!"};
         alert(msg)
The output i wish is: Great! You ansewred 27 out of 30 questions! or Well done! You answered 15 out of 30 questions! or Sorry!  You failed the exam! You only got 9 correct answers! 
         window.location = "myurl.html";
         }

Comment: After *which* piece of data? The name? The email? Can you show an example of the output you desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data .=$_POST["name"];
$data .=' '; //in this line you append space onto the end of the $data string
$data .=$_POST["email"];
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Don't forget the option of &nbsp;  http://www.htmlbasictutor.ca/non-breaking-space.htm

Comment: @Mawg I didn't and gave this option too, but OP wrote it didn't work so I deleted it not to introduce confusion.

Comment: I take note of your smart advices and act in coherence with them.